# Can't build Maven project with Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I was trying to build Maven sample Spring Boot project. I generated Spring Boot project from https://start.spring.io/. I did Maven update. When I run `pom.xml` in Spring Tool Suite IDE using `mvn clean install` command, I get following error.

### Error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.luv2code.springboot.demo:mycoolapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.luv2code.springboot.demo:mycoolapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\nicolas\Dev\workspace\mycoolapp\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.luv2code.springboot.demo:mycoolapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

### My pom.xml and Settings.xml is below

#### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <!-- <relativePath/> lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.luv2code.springboot.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>mycoolapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>mycoolapp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>C:/Users/nicolas/Dev/repo</localRepository>




<pluginGroups>

</pluginGroups>


<proxies>

</proxies>


<servers>

</servers>


<mirrors>

</mirrors>


<profiles>



    <profile>
        <id>securecentral</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from 
the
           Maven Super POM -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

</profiles>


</settings>
```

Comment: https://nanxiao.me/en/set-proxy-for-maven/

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin I updated settings xml with proxies but still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: Your pom works for me apart from the missing project closing tag that I added at the end. But I am using https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ as repository url for Maven Central.

Comment: Hmm Weird, I assume something to do with my settings.xml configuration but not sure what exactly.

Comment: The problem is rleated to this: `(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out and...` meaning network / proxy issue...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build a project using your `pom.xml`, try using with this configuration:

```
<settings>
  ...

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>central</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>central</name>
          <url> http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>central</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  ...
</settings>
```

Also as pointed by @BreakingBenjamin, complement the settings with your proxy configuration:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>mywonderfulproxy.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

If you already did that, please complement your answer with your updated `settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the application successfully by adding below proxy in settings.xml

```
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
    <id>example-proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.example.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
 </proxies>
```